# Android: How to provide AIDL files as source to javadoc?

Tags: android, javadoc

Given that AIDL contain interface definitions, it is important to incorporate them into our javadoc. By default "Generate Javadoc" option in Eclipse only parse files with extension *.java. Is there a javadoc extension for AIDL?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to run the Javadoc generator on the generated .java files the android plugin creates for you from your .aidl files. They are located in the gen folder in your project.

Comment: Exactly. Use ``javadoc -sourcepath "src/;gen/"``